# KnockoutJs validation error message from .html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation, knockout.js

I have a question regarding KnockoutJs html5 validation.

If i wanted to include my error message on the page when it was loaded, like say i am doing a frontend module for my webshop and my error messages comes from tags.

In knockoutJS 2.2.1 i would be able to do this like so:

```
<span data-bind="validationMessage: firstName, text: 'Your error.'"></span>
 <input data-bind='value: firstName, valueUpdate: "input"' required pattern="^[A-Za-z]{1,255}$" />
```

this would work fine and i could paste my errortag into the html page from the html file.
As seen in this fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/elbecita/gt228dgm/4/
However the problem is now that running the same code under knockoutjs 3.0 f.ex. the error message would be "This field is required."

So now i cant overwrite the custom message anymore without doing .extend(), is this intended and am i using this entirely wrong?

A gif to illustrate the issue: http://puu.sh/kHJH3/92a2708c93.gif

I found a similar problem on stackoverflow some of the solutions just seemed overkill but maybe there was a reason?

[Setting error message in html with knockout validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25972294/setting-error-message-in-html-with-knockout-validation) this didnt have any accepted answers,so my question is really how do i paste my error message in the html?

Any input is much appreciated, thank you.

*(if i missed any information please let me know, first post long time lurker)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Validations can have multiple independent messages, so it makes some sense that the contents of the message are taken out of your hands. You choose where they display, but don't have to worry about what they say. I can see that you might want to intercept the standard message and turn it into a custom message. You can do that, but it's not built into validation (as far as I know).

```
viewModel.errors = ko.validation.group(viewModel);
var messageSubstitutes = {
    'Invalid.': 'All letters',
    'This field is required.': 'Try some letters'
};
viewModel.errMsg = ko.computed(function () {
    var errs = viewModel.errors();
    if (errs.length === 0) return null
    var errMsg = errs[0](),        
        result = messageSubstitutes[errMsg];
    return result;
});
```

and the HTML is just:

```
<legend data-bind="if:errMsg">Error: <span data-bind="text:errMsg"></span>

</legend>
<label>First name:
    <input data-bind='value: firstName, valueUpdate: "input"' required pattern="^[A-Za-z]{1,255}$" />
</label>
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gt228dgm/19/)

Comment: This isnt excactly the answer im looking for, i appreciate the way you do it, however that would not work in my case, as i mentioned i need to access the message from outside in the html like mentioned in the post, and im trying to figure out if this is even possible, thanks for the answer however, this was one of the solutions i found aswell, however i would like to do it like in 2.2 as you see in the fiddle it was doable, why isnt it anymore? :)

Comment: If you want to set the message in the HTML, just use `text:'your error'` instead of `text:errMsg` there. I can only guess at the reason for changing from 2.2 to 3.x, and my guess is that they thought it was more useful to have system-generated messages.

Comment: That worked for me, sorry for the long time to answer had to verify things was working, im really starting to enjoy working with knockoutjs most things have a simple solution hidden somewhere, thanks for the help! Cant give you upvotes(new user) but i can give the answer, very well answered.